# How to output the grabbed video into a file with mplayer?

Tags: mplayer

The mplayer command can grab video when to insert usb-camera into usb slot.

```
mplayer -tv driver=v4l2:width=352:height=288:device=/dev/video0 tv://
```

The video grabed by usb-camera can be displayed on the screen,
how to output the grabbed vedio into a file with mplayer?

```
 mplayer -tv driver=v4l2:width=352:height=288:device=/dev/video0 tv://home/test.mp4
```

The command can't grab video into /home/test.mp4.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `dumpstream` option

https://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/streaming.html

```
mplayer -tv driver=v4l2:width=352:height=288:device=/dev/video0  -dumpstream -dumpfile test.mp4   tv://
```

On my install I've sometimes had issues with mp4, so it may be worth trying a different file extension or two to see if it finds a better encoding.